# Mysql import error from bash script

Tags: database, mysql, mysqlimport

i have a big database dump (290mb). When i use import from cli everything is ok!

```
mysql -u root -piddqd whitestore_com < whitestore_com.sql
```

When i use the same command from bash script like:

```
./build.sh
```

Here is what i get:

```
?         (\?) Synonym for `help'.
clear     (\c) Clear the current input statement.
connect   (\r) Reconnect to the server. Optional arguments are db and host.
delimiter (\d) Set statement delimiter.
edit      (\e) Edit command with $EDITOR.
ego       (\G) Send command to mysql server, display result vertically.
exit      (\q) Exit mysql. Same as quit.
go        (\g) Send command to mysql server.
help      (\h) Display this help.
nopager   (\n) Disable pager, print to stdout.
notee     (\t) Don't write into outfile.
pager     (\P) Set PAGER [to_pager]. Print the query results via PAGER.
print     (\p) Print current command.
prompt    (\R) Change your mysql prompt.
quit      (\q) Quit mysql.
rehash    (\#) Rebuild completion hash.
source    (\.) Execute an SQL script file. Takes a file name as an argument.
status    (\s) Get status information from the server.
system    (\!) Execute a system shell command.
tee       (\T) Set outfile [to_outfile]. Append everything into given outfile.
use       (\u) Use another database. Takes database name as argument.
charset   (\C) Switch to another charset. Might be needed for processing binlog with multi-byte charsets.
warnings  (\W) Show warnings after every statement.
nowarning (\w) Don't show warnings after every statement.
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that      corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near 'mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) 
using readline 6.' at line 1
```

I dont know why I get this error, there is no such string as "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) in dump file
    using readline 6."

Answer (score 0):

Try opening up the whitestore_com.sql in a text editor and check the first couple of lines.

It looks like there's some text at the start of the .sql file that should be commented out.

It's opening up the mysql connection ok, but then the commands it's getting from whitestore_com.sql aren't valid SQL statements.

Comment: as i said there is no text like 'mysql Ver ...' in sql file.